# Are Ratings & Reviews going to be in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, software-center

Ratings & Reviews hit Natty yesterday, and I can confirm they're working pretty well. The process is pretty much painless, the interface is straightforward and even server-side, it looks like its working pretty well.

My question is, are we going to see Ratings & Reviews cherrypicked from Natty and backported to Maverick's Software Center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

According to the Software Centre's [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#February%202011) page, ratings and reviews will be released in Maverick in February 2011.

> February 2011
>
> We plan to release Ubuntu Software
>   Center 3.2 for Ubuntu 10.10, with one
>   new feature:
>
> Rating and reviewing software, and
>   seeing ratings and reviews submitted
>   by other Ubuntu users.